# Retrofit indexoutofbounds (empty response)

Tags: android, retrofit

First time using retrofit. I'm not sure why my response keeps on returning null (list is empty; 0 indexes). Here is the github gist:

https://gist.github.com/jtrollkarl/38aea21870ea241dec9c383f7f64056c

I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException at this line: `listofmovies.get(0).getOriginalLanguage();` in RefreshMovies.java

Tested with postman and my request does return as expected. It returns a Page object, in which I try to pull a list of movies with Page.getMovies;

Answer (score 0):

Your service URL doesn't match the API:

@GET("/3/movie/{type}/")

https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/discover

Use a tool like postman to create an http request (with your api key) that works and then code it.

Comment: The request that is returned from movies.request().url(); is valid; it displays json data in my browser. Why then is the list still empty? I don't believe I'm using the api incorrectly. https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/authentication

Answer (score 0):

first check back-end that respond JSON array contain brackets [{,.}]

Comment: Checked with postman and the response is valid and does contain brackets.